# value={{ string }} gives only 1 word of the string

Tags: html, django

```
   {% for q, con in questions_dict.items %}
    <form action="{% url 'psycho:modify_question' %}", method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="hidden" name="oldtext" value={{ q }}>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Text of your question" name="text" value={{ q }}
```

even if q equals "The Count of Monte Cristo" full book, only the first word is displayed on the page. If I do

```
       {% for q, con in questions_dict.items %}
    <form action="{% url 'psycho:modify_question' %}", method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ q }}
        <input type="hidden" name="oldtext" value={{ q }}>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Text of your question" name="text" value={{ q }}
```

I see the full string. How to fix this?

Comment: `<input type="hidden" name="oldtext" value="{{ q }}">` <- quote the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a clever guy Nilost pointed out in the comments, quoting the value(in my case, `<input type="hidden" name="oldtext" value="{{ q }}">` fixes the problem.